# Programming cypress CY8C5566AXI-061

Tags: microcontroller

I am trying to program PSoC5 CY8C5566AXI-061 on a custom made PCB using 5pin connector, with miniprog3  (active protocol: SWD). The CY8C5566AXI-061 is detected correctly in PSoC Creator. In PSoC programmer it's detected as CY8C5586AXI-061.

The board is powered from external source.

Anyways, when I try to program it from PSoC Creator i get the error (same happens from  PSoC Programmer):

```
Error: dbg.M0023: There was an error while programming the device: PSoC Programmer
       reported error (100 - FAILED! SWD respond packet contains Failed status!)
```

(I tried to lower the clock speed but nothing changed)

The settings from PSoC Creator are:

```
Active Protocol: SWD
Clock speed: 1.6MHz
Power: External
Acquire mode: Reset
Connector: 5pin
```

The settings from PSoC Programmer are:

```
Programmer: MiniProg3
Programming mode: Reset
Auto detection: OFF
Protocol: SWD
Voltage: 5V
Connector: 5p
Clock Speed: 1.5MHz
Device: CY8C5566AXI-061
```

The pin connectios from MiniProg3 to PSOC5 (on the custom made PCB) are:

```
VTARG - VDDDIO1 
GND - GND
XRES - XRES (on pin 15)
SCLK - P1[1] (on pin 21)
SDAT - P1[0] (on pin 20)
```

- V<sub>DDIO0</sub>, V<sub>DDIO1</sub>, V<sub>DDIO2</sub>, V<sub>DDIO3</sub>, V<sub>TARG</sub>, V<sub>DDD</sub>, V<sub>DDA</sub> are all conected together to 5V.
- V<sub>SSD</sub>, V<sub>SSA</sub> are connected together to ground.
- The two V<sub>CCD</sub> pins are connected together with 1uF capacitor.
- V<sub>CCA</sub> is connected with 1uF capacitor to ground.

I made the PCB again (now the external supply is 3.3V) and I get the same error. I am struggling with this issue since about 1 week :(

Comment: This is one of the cases in which a schematic is worth more than 1 kWords...

Comment: http://wtrns.fr/3ZSXGR90JRD7xr here is the schematic made in orcad9.2, and the pcb made in protel2.7.1 (old stuff, i know...)

Comment: It's better if you can provide a printout of the schematic, maybe a .png image so that it can be embedded in the question and seen by who doesn't have Orcad.

Comment: Here is the .dxf file for the schematic. You can open it with SolidWorks eDrawings or other dxf viewer. http://wtrns.fr/nzrp4XaJ1DGXnNM

Comment: The other option is power cycle. I tryed that too.

Comment: DXF is not a graphic format.  Try again.

Comment: Hope .pdf would help. http://wtrns.fr/y_FlD5542CwlPf9

Comment: Can you please create a Tech Support case in the Cypress Website or start a forum post attaching your schematic in pdf version so that we can look into the issue? Regards,
Kishore.
Applications Engineer,
Cypress Semiconductor

Comment: I posted in cypress forum in "PSoC 5 Device Programming " area, my topic is "Programming PSoC5 with miniprog3 using 5pin connector" and i reached the point when i get no more answers. I am new with cypress' products.

Comment: You used Inkscape as I see, so Y U NO export it in .png image???

Answer (score 2):

I'm putting the summary of this issue as it has got resolved in the Cypress Forum - http://www.cypress.com/?app=forum&id=2233&rID=60040

For 68-pin & 100-pin packages of PSoC 3/5, P1.2 can be used as an "Optional XRES" pin apart from the dedicated XRES pin. So if you want to program the device using Reset mode of programming, you need to use the dedicated XRES pin (pin no 15) for the first time as only that pin is  configured as XRES in the factory. And if P1.2 needs to be used as an XRES pin thereafter, we need to enable this Optional xres pin in .cydwr file -> Systems tab (in PSoC Creator) while programming the device for the first time.

As we already have a dedicated XRES pin, it is recommended to use that pin for programming the device using reset mode of programming.

For 48-pin package of PSoC 3/5, P1.2 (though Optional XRES pin) comes as an XRES pin from the factory itself and can be used as a reset pin for reset mode of programming during first time itself. But thereafter if we need to program the device using reset mode of programming, then we need to enable the Optional XRES option in the .cydwr file (as told above) for the first time programming itself. Otherwise, we need to use MiniProg3 Rev *B which supports Power cycle mode of programming.

Answer (score 0):

It's very possible there's an error on your board - likely in the reset circuitry.  Otherwise I believe I've had luck with this sort of problem in the past by changing the acquire mode from Reset to... um, something else.  I don't know what the options are offhand - can you give a full list of acquire mode options as well as the complete schematic in a graphic format?